# Polymer 2.0 - How do I use iron-ajax?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to bind local `properties.json` and trying to create dynamic elements, but the problem is I am not getting any console errors and not seeing JSON in the UI.

I didn't find a Polymer 2.0 example for using `<iron-ajax>`, but I found ones for Polymer 1.0 only.

Here's the code I've tried:

**polymer-input.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="polymer-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <iron-ajax auto="" url="properties.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse]]">
      <span>[[item.name]]</span>
    </template>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!..[[ajaxResponse]]</h2>

  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class PolymerApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'polymer-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'polymer-app'
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(PolymerApp.is, PolymerApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>polymer</title>
    <meta name="description" content="custom ele">


    <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="polymer-app/polymer-app.html">
    <link rel="import" href="polymer-input/polymer-input.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <polymer-app></polymer-app>
   </body>
</html>
```

properties.json:

```
{
  {
    name:"Name",
    type:"string",
    size:20
  },
  {
    name:"Age",
    type:"number",
    size:20
  }
}
```

I am getting below output instead of properties json data
[image]

Comment: `auto` is a flag attribute, just like `hidden`, so remove the `=""` after it. Also, do you see that the file was received in the developers tool, under the tab "Network"? Other than that, all i can do is give you an upvote, because i am having the same problem and no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: The three URLs starting with https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/ are 404. And, 0.5 is not even Polymer 1.0. They are quite different, and incompatible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first problem is your demo uses a base URL for Polymer 0.5, while your code is using Polymer 2.0 syntax.
That is, this code:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
```

...should be something like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
```

Second, your `properties.json` file contains invalid JSON. It looks like you meant to use square brackets for array data; and your keys are missing quotes. You'll notice that running the file contents through `JSON.parse()` would throw an error.
This text:

```
{
  {
    name:"Name",
    type:"string",
    size:20
  },
  {
    name:"Age",
    type:"number",
    size:20
  }
}
```

...should be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Name",
    "type":"string",
    "size":20
  },
  {
    "name":"Age",
    "type":"number",
    "size":20
  }
]
```

Third, note that `<iron-ajax>` automatically sets [`<iron-ajax>.lastResponse`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax#property-lastResponse) to `null` if [`<iron-ajax>.handleAs`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax#property-handleAs) is `json` and the response cannot be parsed as JSON. In your case, the invalid JSON in `properties.json` would cause `lastResponse` to be set to `null`, preventing your example from rendering the intended fields.

Here's a working Polymer 2 `<iron-ajax>` demo (using your example code) with all corrections made:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2mpJd1b0UF5FqAr2BOxL?p=preview

Comment: @NagaSaiA No problem :)

Comment: The plnkr example doesn't work in IE. IE users still exist (unfortunately). Is there a way to make it work in IE?